# Definition of the Smallest $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Follad's Real Analysis (pg. 22), he states that the minimum $\sigma$-algebra for some $x\subset \mathcal{P} (X)$ is unique and denoted $\mathcal{M}(x)$. I struggle to understand how $\mathcal{M}(x)$ is unique. Suppose $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $x=\{1,2\}$ and $y=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$. As the additional element in $y$ is the complement wouldn't $\mathcal{M}(x)=\mathcal{M}(y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\subset\mathcal P(X)$, then the set$$\Sigma=\{A\subset\mathcal P(x)\mid x\subset A\text{ and $A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra}\}$$is such that $\bigcap_{A\in\Sigma}A$ is again a $\sigma$-algebra. Besides, it is clear that $x\subset\bigcap_{A\in\Sigma}A$. So, there cannot be a $\sigma$-algebra containing $x$ which is strictly smaller than $\bigcap_{A\in\Sigma}A$ (in other words, $\mathcal M(x)=\bigcap_{A\in\Sigma}A$).

Concerning your example, yes, $\mathcal M(x)=\mathcal M(y)$. But what Folland is saying is that for *each* $x\subset X$, there is one and only one minimal $\sigma$-algebra containing $x$. He is *not* saying that $x\ne y\implies\mathcal M(x)\ne\mathcal M(y)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought he was saying unique for all subsets not just unique for each subset. Thank you for the clarification